# Faster Image with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, matchtemplate

I am working on a project that would help me learn python. I wanted to create a program that would automate a minigame. The minigame have a pointer above a bar and the bar will have three colors in it (green, yellow, red). The point of the game is to click left mouse when the pointer is above the green or yellow section. I found some code on gitlab for this but it is a little too slow and so I was wondering if anyone could give me tips on getting it to run faster. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import mouse
import mss
import time

DEBUG = True

detection_threshold = 0.8
monitor = {'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'width': 2560, 'height': 1440}
target_offset_ver = 75  # Pixels
target_offset_hor = 10  # Pixels
target_color = [20, 138, 38]  # Green bar (BGR)

leaf_icon = cv2.imread("Pointer.bmp")
leaf_icon_depth, leaf_icon_width, leaf_icon_height = leaf_icon.shape[::-1]

with mss.mss() as sct:

    while True:

        # Get screen capture.
        img = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)

        # Find the leaf icon on screen.
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, leaf_icon, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

        # If a leaf is detected.
        if max_val > detection_threshold:

            # Check if the leaf is above the green/yellow bar.
            if np.all(img[max_loc[1] + target_offset_ver, max_loc[0] + target_offset_hor] == target_color):
                print("Leaf is above green bar.")
                mouse.click("left")
            else:
                print("Leaf not in correct position.")

            if DEBUG:
                img[max_loc[1] + target_offset_ver, max_loc[0] + target_offset_hor] = [0, 255, 255]
                cv2.circle(img, (max_loc[0] + target_offset_hor, max_loc[1] + target_offset_ver), 2, 255, 1)

        else:
            print("No leaf detected.")

        if DEBUG:
            # Add a rectangle around the leaf on the image for debug purposes.
            top_left = max_loc
            bottom_right = (top_left[0] + leaf_icon_width, top_left[1] + leaf_icon_height)
            cv2.rectangle(img, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
            cv2.imshow("derp", img)

        # Exit on 'q' press.
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

The mouse click seems to be a bit delayed and misses about 1/5 of the time. I think part of the issue is from `res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, leaf_icon, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)` which takes about 0.25 seconds to complete. Is this because I'm capturing all of the monitor (2560x1440)? Is there anything else I could do to make the delay between grabbing the image and clicking the mouse smaller?

Comment: yes, don't grab the entire screen, or at least don't _work on_ the entire screen.

Comment: Maybe see if you can scale the screengrab down by a factor of 2-4 in each direction, as well as the leaf and still find it successfully. Maybe choose a smaller, but unique subset/part of the leaf and see if that is enough for your needs.